# Square of an Integral into Single Integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I have an integral of the form
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{exp}(-t^2) \cos t^2 ~dt\right)^{2}.
\end{align*}
Is there any way to represent it into single integral form?.
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{exp}(-t^2) \cos t^2~dt\right)^{2}=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{exp}(-(x^2+t^2)) \cos x^2\cos t^2  ~dxdt.
\end{align*}

Comment: \begin{align} \left(\int_{0}^{1} \exp(-t^{2}) \cos(t^{2}) dt \right)^{2} &= \left(\int_{0}^{1} \exp(-t^{2}) \cos(t^{2}) dt \right) \cdot \left(\int_{0}^{1} \exp(-s^{2}) \cos(s^{2}) ds \right) \\ &= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \exp(-(s^2+t^2)) \cos(s^2) \cos(t^2) ds dt \end{align}

Comment: I mean as a single integral. Its a product which is very simple. Like $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)~dx$